# Can denyhost cause error ssh_exchange_identification: connection closed?

Tags: ssh

Since yesterday I can't access my remote server via ssh. It gives me an error connection closed. Even after a reboot I can't access the server and I'm getting the same error again and again. Can it be denyhosts not wanting me anymore?

```
 OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1b 26 Apr 2012
 debug1: Connecting to www.chihoang.de [78.46.220.237] port 22.
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
 debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
 debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
 debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
 debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
 debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
 ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I've a rescue system and I think I can boot into that and try my user and then deinstall denyhosts? I've tried clients on cygwin, Suse and Windows to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be indeed denyhosts, probably you have disabled password logins. Your log shows that you don't have no public/private key pair generated. Have you checked the denyhosts FAQ before installing it? http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Comment: I did it a while ago my error was that I didn't add a big range enough to cover my dynamic ip. Now I'm locked!